# FxCop Nant Task Error: Error creating FileSet

Tags: nant, fxcop

I am getting following error whenever I run fxcop nant task.

**Error creating FileSet.**

Does anybody know what could be the reason?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason behind the issue. Recently I had downloaded Binary Zip of latest NantContrib project. After downloading the zip, I extracted it without unblocking. As I am using Windows Server 2008, all assemblies extracted from the zip were blocked. The FxCop nant task is defined in NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll(which was locked). FxCop task needs IO permission to save report on the machine. Since the file were blocked, fxcop task was throwing exception due to lack of IO permissions.

To resolve this, I just unblocked the zip and re-extracted the NantContrib files. Thereafter everything worked fine.

Thanks Soner!!! Sorry about not being so specific :)

Thanks,

Sachin P